# Cluster computing drop-in replacement for Python multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, programming, distributed

Python has a very handy `multiprocessing` built-in module.  Particularly its `Pool` class allows simple parallelization.  However, it only supports a shared-memory multiprocessing model, not a distributed memory model like is used in cluster computing (like `MPI`).  There are tools like `mpi4py` that allow distributed memory processing in Python, but the ones I have been able to find use substantially different semantics.

Is anyone aware of a distributed memory package for Python that offers a roughly drop-in replacement for the built-in `multiprocessing.Pool` class?

Comment: The following may be of some help: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing

Comment: I looked through that but couldn't find anything that could do this as far as I could see.